# How to create a table from backup file in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

After making some schema change in table `message` in postgresql 13 database, the table is backed up in `pgadmin4` in a file named `message.sql`. The schema change needs to be populated in another database. What I did is to drop the table `message` in that database. But I have hard time to re-create table `message` from the backup file `messages.sql` (not using `CREATE table message ....`). I use pg_restore to restore data but was not successful for re-creating table schema. Here is command I tried with no luck:

```
pg_restore --data-only -h localhost -U postgres -W -d dynamo -t messages /home/download/messages.sql

pg_restore --clean -h localhost -U postgres -W -d dynamo -t messages /home/download/messages.sql
```

I also tried to create an blank table (no column) called `messages` in the database and repeated above command, again without luck.

Comment: What happened?  Reading error messages is better than hoping for luck.

Comment: No error. no schema either.

Comment: A `.sql` script is restored using `psql`. `pg_restore` is for backups take with the "custom format" (`pg_dump -Fc ...`)

Comment: I used pg_restore to restore data from .sql.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a new table is added to the current database:

1. backup the current db on the server with pg_dump
2. create the new database on dev PC with addition of new table
3. On dev PC, use `pgadmin` to restore the backup file in step 1 to new database created in step 2.
4. backup in `pgadmin` and create a `.backup` file for db in step 3.
5. on server, use `pg_restore` to overwrite the current db with new database backup file created in step 4:

   `pg_restore --clean -U postgres --dbname=mydb -W -h localhost --verbose /home/download/mydb.backup`
6. open psql terminal to verify the new table